lutris can run a program installer using wine that I can't successfully run using just wine
I'm using wine-9.15 (Staging) I setup the prefix with WINEARCH=win32. When I try to run the setup.exe with wine I get the following error.
0150:err:module:import_dll Library MFC30.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\USER\\EDINST\\STUB32.EXE") not found
When using lutris the install runs fine. How is it dealing with this missing dll? As far as I can tell the MFC30.dll is not on my system. If there is a library override being used by lutris in winecfg I can't tell which of the overrides is the one helping. Is lutris using something from winetricks?
